# How terminus(multiplatform app) connected to my host without SHH key?

Tags: ssh, terminal, sftp

I created a debian based lamp instance on cloud platform used putty gen to generate ssh saved public key in cloud account. It booted and ip address in browser address said it is working (apache welcome page) Logged in with putty terminal and winscp. Made few changes. Everything is fine

Then to have things at handy i installed terminus ipad app on my ipad to start i used only root and password then it got me in without even asking for ssh even sftp is working. Didn't i setup ssh properly? or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe more information is needed to properly answer your question, but it sounds to me like you want to confirm that ssh key authentication is set up properly.

When you set up key authentication on linux you need to specify all of the keys of the devices that will be used to connect to the linux server in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file

Once the key(s) is added to that file, ssh will use key authentication, but note that password authentication will still be on option. What it looks like you are seeing here is that the original key you added was for one device, so that device it will be able to use either password auth or key auth (typically it will always default to password auth unless you use the `ssh -i` (which stands for identity file) option to specifically use key authentication. The reason your new device is not prompting you for key auth is you have not added the new devices key to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. Thus, it is only prompting for password.

In order to use *only* key authentication, you will have to edit the following in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`to disable password authentication:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Refer to the following for additional documentation: https://back2basics.io/2020/04/setup-public-key-authentication-on-ubuntu-or-debian/

If this is not the answer you are looking for, please comment with further information or add to your existing question.

Comment: thanks for answering some critical error occurred so I deleted my instance and tried to solve it in Local environment with same scenario